# Can I grab songs with a specific tag, and automatically add them to a playlist?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, soundcloud

I'm building a website that has musical writing prompts, and encourages users to record and upload their results to soundcloud with a specific tag (one for each writing prompt). This is so other users can see what people have done with each writing prompt, as I have the toneden.io soundcloud player embedded into each prompt.

I can easily get toneden to play playlists, but not just all songs with a certain tag. Is there a way to automatically add songs with a certain tag to a playlist?

Comment: any code? anything which we can make/suggest changes to??

Answer (score 0):

You can add a tags filter in your API query.

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
          stream = new Audio(),
          client_id = '?client_id=d4ab52d80ed2e7790c3a243495b30093',
          random = $('#tagfield').val();
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?tags=' + random + '&' + client_id);
    xhr.onload = function(){
        var list =JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        var html = "<h2>TAG:"+random+"</h2>";
        for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            html += list[i].title + "</br>"
        }
        $('#results').html(html);
    };
    xhr.send();
});
```

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srkt55ch/1/)**